# C# Panel - Drawing issue

Tags: c#, winforms, 2d, drawing

I'm trying to code my own Game Editor for my next games, though there are some small problems I've encountered as I was working on the TileMap Creator, I've made a Panel and begun to draw small 32x32 rectangles based on the Width & Height of the map, all good until now, but if I try to increase the map size let's say 300x300 nothing shows on the window and I will have to fullscreen resize the window in order to see the rectangles .

I've posted an image describing the problem and the code.
Does anyone have any idea why it's showing like that ?

[image: Image of the problem]

Code :

```
private List<Rectangle> Rectangles = new List<Rectangle>();
private Graphics g;

private void mapArea_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    g = e.Graphics;

    if (Rectangles.Count != 0)
        g.DrawRectangles(Pens.LightGray, Rectangles.ToArray());
}
private void GameEditor_SizeChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    mapArea.Size = new Size(this.Size.Width, this.Size.Height);

}
private void mapTab_newMap_createMap_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < Convert.ToInt32(mapTab_mapWidth.TextBoxText); i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < Convert.ToInt32(mapTab_mapHeight.TextBoxText); j++)
        {
            Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(new Point(i * 32, j * 32), new Size(32, 32));
            Rectangles.Add(rect);
        }
    }
}
```

Also I can't seem to find how to implement a zoom-in / zoom-out / move-by-mouse in a Panel, can it be done ?

Comment: Try calling `mapArea.Invalidate()` after changing its size.

Comment: When your data change you need to trigger the Paint event by Invalidating the Panel. - To implement a zoom you can scale the Graphics object with g.ScaleTransform.

Comment: Thanks guys I will try and I will reply after.

Comment: Note: You seem to __store/cache__ the Graphics object. __Do not do this!__ Only the `e.Graphics` object from the `Paint` event is guaranteed to be valid! You can pass it along to functions that immediately use it but you must not keep it around for later use!

Comment: Thank you very much , I had a hunch that I shouldn't do that. Edit : The first problem is fixed , mapArea.Invalidate() worked as a charm , thank you @adv12